# How can I disable Device Care on Android 13?

Tags: android-13, samsung

I've seen instructions to disable Device Care or limit its operation, but they don't work on Android 13. I don't want some faraway Samsung executive deciding which background applications I can run or which files I can keep. I'm perfectly happy to have the phone tell me which apps are using resources, but I'm quite capable of deciding for myself whether to let them continue doing so. Some of my own apps do run a background service for a long time, because that's what I wrote them to do. I have lots of files on it, but it's the 512GB model, so I'm not running out of space. I don't want large files that I haven't used lately getting removed: they are on the device because I want them there. If I don't want files I can delete them myself: I don't use apps which create unneeded files and leave them lying around. If the built-in apps (most of which I have disabled) create files, they should clean up after themselves.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G which recently upgraded to Android 13.